# Ext Js. Several values in dataindex

Tags: javascript, extjs

I got values in JSON and want to add several values in dataindex. How I can do this?

This works perfectly

```
columns: [
  {
    header: "Records",
    dataIndex: time,
    sortable: true,
  },
];
```

But this example doesn't work

```
columns: [
  {
    header: "Records",
    dataIndex: time + value + value1,
    sortable: true,
  },
];
```

Comment: Why does it not work? What is `time`, `value`, `value1`? What exactly is in JSON format. Please specify your question a little.

Answer (score 1):

Column property `dataIndex` should be a string that is the name of the field in the model definition, [see documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-dataIndex). To add different values from the model and display the result in a grid column, either use a [calculated field](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/modern/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-calculate) and put the calculated field's name to `dataIndex`, or create a [custom renderer function](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-renderer) for the column and add the values there.